# How can I select data in one DB, and use it to insert rows in another DB in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to not write an app to do this, and improve my SQL mojo at the same time...

Say I have data in one database table `Database1.dbo.MyTable` with the following columns:

- ObjectType
- ObjectKeyID

There are thousands of these rows.

In `Database2.dbo.MyOtherTable` I have a slightly different schema, let's say:

- MyKey
- MyValue

I want to take the data from `Database1.dbo.MyTable`, and use each row's data as an INSERT into `Database2.dbo.MyOtherTable`.

My guess is that I have to establish a cursor in a while loop, but not sure of the exact syntax to do that, or if there is a better way. What's the best technique/syntax to use for this?

EDIT: Here's what I ended up using (fields changed for this example), worked great in addition to making sure the keys existed before inserting:

```
INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.MyOtherTable (MyKey, MyValue)
SELECT ObjectType, ObjectKeyID FROM Database1.dbo.MyTable
WHERE ObjectType LIKE 'Widget' AND ObjectKeyID > 0 AND ObjectKey IN (SELECT UserAccountID FROM MyUsers)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can (and should if possible) avoid using a cursor:

```
INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.MyOtherTable (MyKey, MyValue)
SELECT ObjectKeyID, ObjectType FROM Database1.dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: Note: this only works if both MS SQL databases are on the same physical database server.

Comment: Which is so in the question asked by the OP.

Answer (score 6):

You can do a cross-database insert:

```
insert Database2.dbo.MyOtherTable (... columns ...)
    select ...
    from Database1.dbo.MyTable
```